# Disable T-Mobile voicemail to text?

Tags: iphone, voicemail

I currently get a text message for every voicemail I receive on my iPhone, how do I turn that off?

I already have visual voicemail within iOS, so there’s no need for an additional transcript of my voicemails.

On Android, they offer an app for managing voicemail but their support pages and forums don’t contain instructions for how to turn this off on an iPhone. This is a common problem that many customers complain about having a hard time fixing.

Comment: Isn‘t this basically a customer support question for said carrier, and not directly an Apple-related issue?

Comment: I struggle to get help from TMobile, so I’m a bit sympathetic to this being documented here. (They used to be great but it took three calls and two visits to a store to drop my iPad data plan - literally 3+ hours of my life was gone to stop paying for a service I haven’t used for a few months.)

Comment: You can’t easily find an answer to this online (it took customer service an hour to figure it out), it’s a problem that affects all iPhone users who use T-Mobile, and it’s general + practical.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the T-Mobile app:

1. Open “Account” tab
2. Click “Profile settings” link
3. Select “Block...”
4. Select “Block Other” on the line you wish to update
5. Turn on “T-Mobile Voicemail to Text Block”

Comment: One addition after step 3 if you have multiple lines is that you have to select with line for which you want to add the block.

Comment: Thanks @tim.rohrer, I've incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: Good info. Crappy T-Mobile interface.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me just now. Very hard to figure this out.